# Confluent Kafka Consumer.Consume() not able to catch any exceptions ( invalid credentials)

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;

class program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            bool flag = false;
            var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "pkc-6ojv2.us-west4.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092",
                SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
                SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
                SaslUsername = "NUSJ4dsfdfsdKO6A6JA6",
                SaslPassword = "7gSgj1AXyIj/TYuL5v6WWdr/MfpG2Mhxrnzy9XRN8+jvk1/8LpB/A82CHUOW6L1V",
                GroupId = "test",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
                EnableAutoCommit = false
            };
            while (!flag)
            {
                try
                {
            
                    using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
                    {
                        var message = consumer.Consume();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Task.CurrentId} received message: {message.Value}");
                        consumer.Commit(message);
                    }
                }
                catch (ConsumeException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {e.Error.Reason}");
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch (AuthenticationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {e.Message}");
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is the code which is not going to any catch block when the credentials are invalid .

Consumer.Consume() not throwing exception and being caught by any of the catch blocks . please help me with a better approach if any for Exception Handling .
I am Using Confluent.Kafka library on .Net Framework 4.8 .
Thanks

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace of the exception you're seeing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening is that Consumer.Consume will try to recover from all non-fatal errors. To get notified by these errors you have to call SetErrorHandler on ConsumerBuilder so in this case

```
using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(_config).SetErrorHandler(ErrorHandler).Build())
```

where ErrorHandler is

```
private void ErrorHandler(IConsumer<Ignore, string> consumer, Error error)
```

see [Confluent documentation on SetErrorHandler](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder-2.html#Confluent_Kafka_ConsumerBuilder_2_SetErrorHandler_System_Action_Confluent_Kafka_IConsumer__0__1__Confluent_Kafka_Error__)